# multiprocessing - Cancel remaining jobs in a pool without destroying the Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-internals

I'm using map_async to create a pool of 4 workers. And giving it a list of image files to process [Set 1].
At times, I need to cancel the processing in between, so that I can instead get a different set of files processed [Set 2].

So an example situation is, I gave map_async 1000 files to process. And then want to cancel the processing of remaining jobs after about 200 files have been processed.
Additionally, I want to do this cancellation without destroying/terminating the pool. Is this possible?

**I do not want to terminate the pool**, because recreating the pool is a slow process on Windows (because it uses 'spawn', instead of 'fork'). And I need to use this same pool for processing a different set of image files [Set 2]..

```
# Putting job_set1 through processing. It may consist of 1000 images
cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = Pool(processes=cpu)
result = pool.map_async(job_set1, thumb_ts_list, chunksize=chunksize)
```

Now in between, I need to cancel the processing on this set 1. And move onto a different set (waiting for all 1000 images to complete processing is not an option, but I can wait for the current image being processed to finish)

```
<Somehow cancel processing of job_set1>
result = pool.map_async(job_set2, thumb_ts_list, chunksize=chunksize)
```

Comment: This is all very theoretical without any code, but if you want to "cancel" a job which is running in another process, you have basically two options: either kindly ask the other process to stop, by sending it a message somehow, or simply kill the process without kindly asking.

Comment: Following on from @zvone: is it sufficient to _not start_ any more work and let existing tasks complete (even if uselessly)?

Comment: @zvone: So stopping a process by sending a kind message is simple. But we are talking about cancelling queued jobs in a processing job pool. Killing is not an option as I already mentioned in the question..

Comment: @DavisHerring: So I can wait for current image to be processed. But not wait for all the images to be processed... (since it takes quite a lot of time to finish the whole job, and I want to move onto another job)

Comment: @vishal: What’s easy to implement is not “current image” _singular_, but all that are in flight at the moment you decide to cancel.  Is that OK?

Comment: @DavisHerring: Yes. I'm looking to only cancel jobs which are in flight at the moment when I need to trigger the cancellation..

Comment: @vishal: Sorry, I wasn’t clear.  The practical solution cancels tasks that have been “registered” but not yet taken up by any process.  It allows all processes (perhaps as many as you have processor cores?) to finish their current task, thus wasting about half as many tasks as the pool size.  Is _that_ sufficiently responsive?

Comment: @DavisHerring: Right. So I'm using as many processes, as number of processor cores. And am ok to allow them to finish their current task. Sorry, I didn't get what you meant by "thus wasting about half as many tasks as the pool size."?

Comment: On the side, I'm trying a solution with `apply_async` where (1) I create jobs with a maximum chunk size of 100 images. (2) post new jobs only after the previous once has finished processning. (3) in case I need to cancel.. I stop posting new 100 image job requests, and let the previous ones finish.

Comment: Do you need to know how many tasks have been processed when you trigger the cancelation or is it just a kind of timeout?

Answer (score 1):

It's time for the [fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering): while `multiprocessing.Pool` doesn't supply cancellation as a feature, we can add it by having a `Pool` read from a carefully crafted iterable.  It's not enough, however, to have a generator that `yield`s values from a list but stops short on some signal, because the `Pool` eagerly drains any generator given to it.  So we need a *very* carefully crafted iterable.

## A lazy `Pool`

The generic tool we need is a way to construct tasks for a `Pool` only when a worker becomes available (or at most one task ahead, in case constructing them takes significant time).  The basic idea is to slow down the thread collecting work for the `Pool` with a semaphore upped only when a task is finished.  (We know such a thread exists from the observable behavior of `imap_unordered`.)

```
import multiprocessing
from threading import Semaphore

size=multiprocessing.cpu_count()  # or whatever Pool size to use

# How many workers are waiting for work?  Add one to buffer one task.
work=Semaphore(size)

def feed0(it):
  it=iter(it)
  try:
    while True:
      # Don't ask the iterable until we have a customer, in case better
      # instructions become available:
      work.acquire()
      yield next(it)
  except StopIteration: pass
  work.release()
def feed(p,f,it):
  import sys,traceback
  iu=p.imap_unordered(f,feed0(it))
  while True:
    try: x=next(iu)
    except StopIteration: return
    except Exception: traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
    work.release()
    yield x
```

The `try` in `feed` prevents failures in the children from breaking the semaphore's count, but note that it does not protect against failures in the parent.

## A cancelable iterator

Now that we have real-time control over the `Pool` input, making whatever scheduling policy is straightforward.  For example, here's something like `itertools.chain` but with the ability to asynchronously discard any remaining elements from one of the input sequences:

```
import collections,queue

class Cancel:
  closed=False
  cur=()
  def __init__(self): self.data=queue.Queue() # of deques
  def add(self,d):
    d=collections.deque(d)
    self.data.put(d)
    return d
  def __iter__(self):
    while True:
      try: yield self.cur.popleft()
      except IndexError:
        self.cur=self.data.get()
        if self.cur is None: break
  @staticmethod
  def cancel(d): d.clear()
  def close(self): self.data.put(None)
```

This is thread-safe (in CPython at least) despite the lack of locking because operations like `deque.clear` are atomic with respect to Python inspection (and we don't separately check whether `self.cur` is empty).

## Usage

Making one of these looks like

```
pool=mp.Pool(size)
can=Cancel()
many=can.add(range(1000))
few=can.add(["some","words"])
can.close()
for x in feed(pool,assess_happiness,can):
  if happy_with(x): can.cancel(many)  # straight onto few, then out
```

where of course the `add`s and `close` could themselves be in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for having looked into it this deeply :) This answer would surely help me. Might not use it as it is. But simply pick up the parts that I'd need.

Answer (score 0):

The `multiprocessing` module doesn't seem to have the concept of cancellation. You *can* use the [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) wrapper and cancel the pending futures when you have enough results.

Here's an example that picks out 10 JPEGs from a set of paths, and cancels pending futures while leaving the process pool usable afterwards:

```python
import concurrent.futures


def interesting_path(path):
    """Gives path if is a JPEG else ``None``."""
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        if f.read(3) == b'\xff\xd8\xff':
            return path
        return None


def find_interesting(paths, count=10):
     """Yields count from paths which are 'interesting' by multiprocess task."""
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        futures = {pool.submit(interesting_path, p) for p in paths}
        print ('Started {}'.format(len(futures)))
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            res = future.result()
            futures.remove(future)
            if res is not None:
                yield res
                count -= 1
                if count == 0:
                    break
        cancelled = 0
        for future in futures:
            cancelled += future.cancel()
        print ('Cancelled {}'.format(cancelled))
        concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
        # Can still use pool here for more processing as needed
```

Note that picking how to break up work into futures is still tricky, a bigger set is more overhead but can also mean less wasted work. This can also be adapted to Python 3.6 async syntax easily enough.