# Force Multiprocessing Pool to iterate over argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing Pool to run a function for multiple arguments over and over. I use a list for jobs that filled by another thread and a `job_handler` function to handles each job. My problem is that when the list becomes empty the Pool will end the function. I want to keep the pool alive and wait until the list to fill. Actually, there are two scenarios to solve this.

1.Use one pool but would end after list become empty:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def job_handler(i):
    print("Doing job:", i)
    sleep(0.5)

def job_adder():
    i = 0
    while True:
        jobs.append(i)
        i += 1
        sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(4)
    jobs = []
    thr = Thread(target=job_adder)
    thr.start()
    # wait for job_adder to add to list
    sleep(1)
    pool.map_async(job_handler, jobs)
    while True:
        pass
```

2.Multiple `map_async`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def job_handler(i):
    print("Doing job:", i)
    sleep(0.5)

def job_adder():
    i = 0
    while True:
        jobs.append(i)
        i += 1
        sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(4)
    jobs = []
    thr = Thread(target=job_adder)
    thr.start()
    while True:
        for job in jobs:
            pool1 = pool.map_async(job_handler, (job,))
            jobs.remove(job)
```

What is the difference between the two? I think the first option would be nicer because the map itself would handle the iteration. My aim is to get better performance to handle each job separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need to “slow down” a `Pool` comes up in a number of situations.  This case is easier than [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52158659/8586227):

```
q=queue.Queue()
m=pool.imap(iter(q.get,None))
```

You can also use `imap_unordered`; `None` is a sentinel to terminate the `Pool`.  The `Pool` has to use a thread to collect the tasks (since those functions are “lazier [than] `map()`”), and it will block on `q` as needed.

Comment: Thanks, using queue is a good idea. But my problem is when using `imap` force me to get results by `m` that seems a generator but I prefer the callback on `map_async`. Using `queue` with `map_async` didn't work for me.

Comment: @MasoudR.: You can obviously start a thread to consume the returned generator and issue callbacks; `map_async` already does so on a separate thread, so the synchronization requirements are the same.